# NSDate conversion issue in iOs

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I am having a double value that represents a `NSTimeInterval`. I want to create the correct date from the double value, here is my code. I am getting the output, but there is some changes from the actual value.

```
NSString *modiDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1338229800"]; //example time interval value

NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([modiDate doubleValue] - 3600)];
NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];    
NSDate *online = [NSDate date];
online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

What went wrong here? Any idea?

**EDIT:**
For testing first i converted a date to `NSTimeInterval` and tried to get back the date.
Here is the code and output.

```
NSString *modDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5/30/2012 2:02:55 PM"];

NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
NSDate *dateFromString1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString1 = [format dateFromString:modDate];
[format release];
NSTimeInterval timeInterval1 = [dateFromString1 timeIntervalSince1970];

NSLog(@"timeinterval : %f",timeInterval1);

NSDate *online = [NSDate date];
online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval1];    
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

and the output is:

```
 result: 05/30/2012 12:02:55 PM actual date:5/30/2012 2:02:55 PM
```

Comment: What are the changes?  Where is NSLog output?

Comment: i have updated my question with code and results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, NSTimeInterval is a float, so you don't need to use NSString or NSNumber (NSNumber are made for storing numbers in dictionaries or arrays).

You can simplify your code as:

```
NSTimeInterval interval = 1338229800;
interval -= 3600;
NSDate *online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

This give me : `05/28/2012 19:30:00 PM`

It corresponds to the initial value : 1338229800 minus one hour (- 3600 sec).

EDIT :

In your edit, your write :

```
NSString *modDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"5/30/2012 2:02:55 PM"];
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
```

But you should check [the date format paterns page](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns):
`2:02:55 PM`corresponds to `@"h:mm:ss a"` and not to <s>`"HH:mm:ss aaa"`</s>

Comment: yes it is. As I said, everything is explained at http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 1):

There are many thing wrong with this code:

Why create all these object:

```
NSString *modiDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1338229800"]; //example time interval value
NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([modiDate doubleValue] - 3600)];
NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];
```

When this is the same:

```
 NSString *modiDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1338229800"];
 NSTimeInterval interval = [modiDate doubleValue]  - 3600;
```

---

Here you assing a new date to online:

```
NSDate *online = [NSDate date];
```

only to set an other date to online here:

```
online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

You should have done this:

```
NSDate *online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
```

---

I'm sure what you problem with this code, but it works correctly.
You might want to set the locale, not really need but might have some effect in localization:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale systemLocale];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

---

**Added new code from edit**

In your edit you added this code:

```
NSDate *dateFromString1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString1 = [format dateFromString:modDate];
```

Here you are leaking an `NSDate` object,just do this:

```
NSDate *dateFromString1 = [format dateFromString:modDate];
```

And as state in the answer by [martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127493/martin) the problem is in the time format string.

Answer (score 0):

You are using HH which is for 24 hours. Instead use hh (0-12) which is suitable for AM/PM format.